# How do I customize how I display JUnit test results?

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit4

When i ues JUnit to test some java function, It will output some results regardless of success or failure.But sometimes it Looks like a bunch of small ants, makes me dizzy.

**Perhaps the original intention of generating this output is to make better debugging. 
But if there are hundreds or thousands of test cases, the output may not be fully displayed in the console.
So, is there a way to trigger an action when the test fails, just write the failed content to a file or send it to a mailbox?**

E.g:

Sntest.java

```
package com.jut;

public class Sntest {
    public String getString() {
        return "String";
    }
    public Object getNull() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

SntestTest.java

```
package com.jut;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.jut.Sntest;

public class SntestTest {

    @Test
    public void t1() {
        Sntest sn = new Sntest();
        String msg = sn.getString();

        Assert.assertEquals("AString != String", "AString", msg);

    }

    @Test
    public void t2() {
        Sntest sn = new Sntest();
        Assert.assertNull("Not null", sn.getNull());
    }
}
```

In the above example, test method t1 will get the wrong result and display a lot of information, as follows：

```
Running com.jut.SntestTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.156 sec <<< FAILURE!
t1(com.jut.SntestTest)  Time elapsed: 0.025 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: AString != String expected:<[A]String> but was:<[]String>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:125)
        at com.jut.SntestTest.t1(SntestTest.java:15)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

But what I want to see is only the first line to the fourth line.So how can I turn the output into the following result?

```
Running com.jut.SntestTest
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.156 sec <<< FAILURE!
    t1(com.jut.SntestTest)  Time elapsed: 0.025 sec  <<< FAILURE!
    org.junit.ComparisonFailure: AString != String expected:<[A]String> but was:<[]String>
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm afraid it can't change to what you want. it is just a call stack which helps you to locate the problem

Comment: So, is there any way to capture the test cases that failed the test, because if there are many test cases, it is likely that they will not be fully displayed.

Comment: ¿¿ 它本来就只捕捉失败的case